# How enterprise magento2.1 stores product attributes with schedule updates? (row_id)

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, product-attribute, magento-2.1, eav

In Magento2.1 enterprise, schedule updates has been introduced, which changes the table schema of product & other cms page.

Take product attributes as example, a column "row_id" has been added to indicate current value/revision of attributes.

As the changes is quite big, many v2.x extension are unable to use because it cannot map to correct column.
Anyone knows how magento2 handles row_id & product, and any opinions for migrating old extension to support this new schema?

[image: magento2.1 product eav varchar table]